# show a div when a row is inserted in a table

Tags: php, ajax

i have 2 pages one is GoogleMap.php this shows a div contains a map with specific longitude and latitude taken from mobile , and in the other page i want to show a div contains that map only when a new longitude and latitude inserted in a database .How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a framework something that provides websockets support or (since all browsers don't support it yet...fallback to long polling). Here's a [great article](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-advanced-polling-with-jquery) that provides several techniques to help you accomplish what you want.

Comment: m thinking to use ajax , can i do that using ajax ? and how can i show the div or hide it directly when a new row is inserted in the table ?

Comment: I really can't help you if you don't even bother reading the link I provided.